# jQuery Div Notification Alert Syntax on Pusher Notification

Tags: jquery, html, pusher

I am pushing an event via pusher to the following code:
I am not getting the expected html from  alertDivNotification.

```
<!-- output -->
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert">Hello</div>

<!-- expected -->
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  <strong>Moving Servers</strong> Hello
</div>
```

```js
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  var alertDivNotification = $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Moving Servers</strong> message</div>');
  alertDivNotification.html(data.message);
  $('#alertDivContainer').prepend(alertDivNotification);
});
```

Comment: What happens instead? Do you receive the Pusher event in your event handler? You could check by adding a log line above your `var alertDivNotification = ...`. You could also add `pusher.logToConsole = true;` and show us your logs.

Comment: I also think your `.html(...)` is going to remove the `<button>` and the `<strong>` in your div. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @jameshfisher  yes the pusher event is triggered correctly, the html div is missing elements .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
var alertDivNotification = $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Moving Servers</strong> message</div>');
alertDivNotification.html(data.message);
```

I assume you want the `data.message` from the Pusher event to replace the literal word "message" in your HTML. But the jQuery `.html` method is replacing all children of your `<div>`, including your button. Instead, use `.append`, appending a text node constructed from the `data.message`. Like this:

```
var alertDivNotification = $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Moving Servers</strong></div>');
alertDivNotification.append(document.createTextNode(data.message));
```

(Edit) If you want to add a `data.notification_title` to your Pusher event and display that, you can:

```
var alertDivNotification = $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button></div>');
alertDivNotification.append($('<strong></strong>').append(document.createTextNode(data.notification_title)));
alertDivNotification.append(document.createTextNode(data.message));
```

Comment: how would you add a (data.notification_title) between the <strong>{{data.notification_title}}</strong>?

Comment: @dflow I've edited my answer with a suggestion (untested). Hope it helps!